# How do I get rid of stale water smell in my new dishwasher

Tags: cleaning, smell

I have a foul stale smell in my new dishwasher, in spite of the the things they tell you to do.  I have also had the engineer out and they say nothing wrong. I am sure it is to do with the filter.  My old dishwasher filter always had lots to clean out, this one always, every time I check, has none.  Comments please

Comment: Did you try to clean it using any of  [dishwasher cleaning liquids](https://www.google.pl/search?q=dishwasher+cleaning+liquid&client=opera&hs=0FR&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju3Li_z6nVAhWhBZoKHba_AMYQsAQIPg&biw=1093&bih=651)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert.  But, dealing with things that smell stale (mold?, bacteria?, other?) there's a short laundry list of things I'd try.

- CLR (Calcium, lime, rust removal)  Does wonders for a lot of things.
- Vinegar and salt -  The vinegar is acidic in nature and kills lots of things.  The salt is also violently brutal to other things that are unbothered by acid.

I did say it was a short list.

As an aside, most laundromats will keep the doors to the machines open. This is done, even if only cracked open a bit, so the machine can "breathe" the water out, thus helping to prohibit growth.  If there is a way to chalk the door open, just a bit, to help the machine breathe, I think it might help regardless of the others.

Comment: I have done all of these. The dishwasher is new. I am convinced it is a filter problem.